# How to make part of an image clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have a picture of a clock (background of my main page) and I want to make the hours on the clock clickable so by clicking 1 pm it opens another page. I want to have a different page for each hour. Can i use the "a tag" to do this? I want an html or css code and not JAVA. I'm trying to create this on dreamweaver so I'm hoping the code would actually work on dreamweaver. Can someone help me out with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `map` tag in html http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: throught image mapping

Answer (score 4):

An image-map is the simplest way of doing this.

To do so you simply need to define a shape - or a number of shapes - and co-ordinates for them. For example:

```
<img src="image.gif" width="150" height="150" alt="anImage" usemap="#examplemap">

<map name="examplemap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,90,150" href="page1.html" alt="Page1">
  <area shape="circle" coords="115,50,10" href="page2.html" alt="Page2">
</map>
```

As you can see the image is placed, as normal, but it references the image map that you define for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an HTML5/CSS3 based clock that requires no images or JavaScript and has clickable hour numbers that are simple `<a>` tags.** A very simple and elegant solution. You could easily add a background image to the clockface to make it look even better, etc.

I found a CSS3 clock on CodePen and modified it so that the hour numbers are clickable on the clock. For the hands to move around it uses CSS animations and also CSS shapes. Here's the **[working code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQzmoe)**.

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="watch">
  <div class="frame-face"></div>
  <ul class="minute-marks">
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="digital-wrap">
    <ul class="digit-hours">
      <li>23</li>
      <li>00</li><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li>
      <li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li>
      <li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li>
      <li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="digit-minutes">
      <li>10</li><li>11</li>
      <li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li>
      <li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li>
      <li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li><li>27</li><li>28</li><li>29</li>
      <li>30</li><li>31</li><li>32</li><li>33</li><li>34</li><li>35</li>
      <li>36</li><li>37</li><li>38</li><li>39</li><li>40</li><li>41</li>
      <li>42</li><li>43</li><li>44</li><li>45</li><li>46</li><li>47</li>
      <li>48</li><li>49</li><li>50</li><li>51</li><li>52</li><li>53</li>
      <li>54</li><li>55</li><li>56</li><li>57</li><li>58</li><li>59</li>
      <li>00</li><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li>
      <li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="digit-seconds">
      <li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li>
      <li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li><li>27</li><li>28</li><li>29</li>
      <li>30</li><li>31</li><li>32</li><li>33</li><li>34</li><li>35</li>
      <li>36</li><li>37</li><li>38</li><li>39</li><li>40</li><li>41</li>
      <li>42</li><li>43</li><li>44</li><li>45</li><li>46</li><li>47</li>
      <li>48</li><li>49</li><li>50</li><li>51</li><li>52</li><li>53</li>
      <li>54</li><li>55</li><li>56</li><li>57</li><li>58</li><li>59</li>
      <li>00</li><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li>
      <li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li>
      <li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li>
      <li>18</li><li>19</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="digits">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="hours-hand"></div>
  <div class="minutes-hand"></div>
  <div class="seconds-hand"></div>
</div>
```

**THE CSS**

```
body { font-size:62.5%; margin:1em; background:#232425 }
ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0 }
#watch { font-size:1em; position:relative }
#watch .frame-face {
  position:relative;
  width:30em;
  height:30em;
  margin:2em auto;
  border-radius:15em;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9,#666);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9,#666);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9,#666);
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.8) .5em .5em 4em;
}
#watch .frame-face:before {
  content:'';
  width:29.4em;
  height:29.4em;
  border-radius:14.7em;
  position:absolute;
  top:.3em; left:.3em;
  background:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(246,248,249,0) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,0) 100%),
    -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 65%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 66%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
  background:
    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(246,248,249,0) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,0) 100%),
    -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 65%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 66%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(246,248,249,0) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 50%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 51%,rgba(245,247,249,0) 100%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 65%,rgba(205,212,217,1) 66%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%);
}
#watch .frame-face:after {
  content:'';
  width:28em;
  height:28em;
  border-radius:14.2em;
  position:absolute;
  top:.9em; left:.9em;
  box-shadow:inset rgba(0,0,0,.2) .2em .2em 1em;
  border:.1em solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ccc);
}
#watch .minute-marks li {
  display:block;
  width:.2em;
  height:.6em;
  background:#929394;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin:-.4em 0 0 -.1em;
}
#watch .minute-marks li:first-child {transform:rotate(6deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(2) {transform:rotate(12deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(3) {transform:rotate(18deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(4) {transform:rotate(24deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(5) {transform:rotate(36deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(6) {transform:rotate(42deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(7) {transform:rotate(48deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(8) {transform:rotate(54deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(9) {transform:rotate(66deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(10) {transform:rotate(72deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(11) {transform:rotate(78deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(12) {transform:rotate(84deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(13) {transform:rotate(96deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(14) {transform:rotate(102deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(15) {transform:rotate(108deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(16) {transform:rotate(114deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(17) {transform:rotate(126deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(18) {transform:rotate(132deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(19) {transform:rotate(138deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(20) {transform:rotate(144deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(21) {transform:rotate(156deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(22) {transform:rotate(162deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(23) {transform:rotate(168deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(24) {transform:rotate(174deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(25) {transform:rotate(186deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(26) {transform:rotate(192deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(27) {transform:rotate(198deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(28) {transform:rotate(204deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(29) {transform:rotate(216deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(30) {transform:rotate(222deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(31) {transform:rotate(228deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(32) {transform:rotate(234deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(33) {transform:rotate(246deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(34) {transform:rotate(252deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(35) {transform:rotate(258deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(36) {transform:rotate(264deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(37) {transform:rotate(276deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(38) {transform:rotate(282deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(39) {transform:rotate(288deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(40) {transform:rotate(294deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(41) {transform:rotate(306deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(42) {transform:rotate(312deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(43) {transform:rotate(318deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(44) {transform:rotate(324deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(45) {transform:rotate(336deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(46) {transform:rotate(342deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(47) {transform:rotate(348deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .minute-marks li:nth-child(48) {transform:rotate(354deg) translateY(-12.7em)}
#watch .digits {
  width:30em;
  height:30em;
  border-radius:15em;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:50%;
  margin-left:-15em;
}
#watch .digits li {
  font-size:1.6em;
  display:block;
  width:1.6em;
  height:1.6em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  line-height:1.6em;
  text-align:center;
  margin:-.8em 0 0 -.8em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#watch .digits li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}
#watch .digits li:nth-child(1) { transform:translate(3.9em, -6.9em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(2) { transform:translate(6.9em, -4em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(3) { transform:translate(8em, 0) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(4) { transform:translate(6.8em, 4em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(5) { transform:translate(3.9em, 6.9em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(6) { transform:translate(0, 8em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(7) { transform:translate(-3.9em, 6.9em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(8) { transform:translate(-6.8em, 4em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(9) { transform:translate(-8em, 0) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(10) { transform:translate(-6.9em, -4em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(11) { transform:translate(-3.9em, -6.9em) }
#watch .digits li:nth-child(12) { transform:translate(0, -8em) }
#watch .digits:before {
  content:'';
  width:1.6em;
  height:1.6em;
  border-radius:.8em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin:-.8em 0 0 -.8em;
  background:#121314;
}
#watch .digits:after {
  content:'';
  width:4em;
  height:4em;
  border-radius:2.2em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin:-2.1em 0 0 -2.1em;
  border:.1em solid #c6c6c6;
  background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(200,200,200,0), rgba(190,190,190,1) 90%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 100%);
  background:-moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(200,200,200,0), rgba(190,190,190,1) 90%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 100%);
  background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(200,200,200,0), rgba(190,190,190,1) 90%, rgba(130,130,130,1) 100%);
}
@keyframes hours { to {transform:rotate(335deg)} }
#watch .hours-hand {
  width:.8em;
  height:7em;
  border-radius:0 0 .9em .9em;
  background:#232425;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%; left:50%;
  margin:0 0 -.8em -.4em;
  box-shadow:#232425 0 0 2px;
  transform-origin:0.4em 6.2em;
  transform:rotate(-25deg);
  animation:hours 43200s linear 0s infinite;
}
#watch .hours-hand:before {
  content:'';
  background:inherit;
  width:1.8em;
  height:.8em;
  border-radius:0 0 .8em .8em;
  box-shadow:#232425 0 0 1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-.7em; left:-.5em;
}
#watch .hours-hand:after {
  content:'';
  width:0; height:0;
  border:.9em solid #232425;
  border-width:0 .9em 2.4em .9em;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:-3.1em; left:-.5em;
}
@keyframes minutes { to {transform:rotate(422deg)} }
#watch .minutes-hand {
  width:.8em;
  height:12.5em;
  border-radius:.5em;
  background:#343536;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%; left:50%;
  margin:0 0 -1.5em -.4em;
  box-shadow:#343536 0 0 2px;
  transform-origin:0.4em 11em;
  transform:rotate(62deg);
  animation:minutes 3600s linear 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes seconds { to {transform:rotate(480deg)} }
#watch .seconds-hand {
  width:.2em;
  height:14em;
  border-radius:.1em .1em 0 0/10em 10em 0 0;
  background:#c00;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%; left:50%;
  margin:0 0 -2em -.1em;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0 0 .2em;
  transform-origin:0.1em 12em;
  transform:rotate(120deg);
  animation:seconds 60s steps(60, end) 0s infinite;
}
#watch .seconds-hand:after {
  content:'';
  width:1.4em;
  height:1.4em;
  border-radius:.7em;
  background:inherit;
  position:absolute;
  left:-.65em; bottom:1.35em;
}
#watch .seconds-hand:before {
  content:'';
  width:.8em;
  height:3em;
  border-radius:.2em .2em .4em .4em/.2em .2em 2em 2em;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0 0 .2em;
  background:inherit;
  position:absolute;
  left:-.35em; bottom:-3em;
}
#watch .digital-wrap {
  width:9em;
  height:3em;
  border:.1em solid #222;
  border-radius:.2em;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin:3em 0 0 -4.5em;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#4c4c4c;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%,#0f0f0f 100%);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%, #0f0f0f 100%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%,#0f0f0f 100%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%,#0f0f0f 100%);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #4c4c4c 0%,#0f0f0f 100%);
}
#watch .digital-wrap ul {
  float:left;
  width:2.85em;
  height:3em;
  border-right:.1em solid #000;
  color:#ddd;
  font-family:Consolas, monaco, monospace;
}
#watch .digital-wrap ul:last-child { border:none }
#watch .digital-wrap li {
  font-size:1.5em;
  line-height:2;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  left:1px;
}
#watch .digit-minutes li {
  animation:dsm 3600s steps(60, end) 0s infinite;
}
#watch .digit-seconds li {
  animation:dsm 60s steps(60, end) 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes dsm {
  to { transform:translateY(-120em) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use map and area to make some of part clickable .

```
HTML <area> Tag, An image-map, with clickable areas:
```

More Info : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 1):

Image maps would work just fine; however the map needs to match perfectly with the image.

The more robust solution is to do the clock as an SVG in which you place links, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125451/3318612.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<area>` tag. This is done by using html.
More Detail you See This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link).