How to make png files interactive with JavaScript?
How to make png files interactive with JavaScript? The aim would be to open an html page (with information) by clicking with the mouse cursor on some specific parts of the png image. I welcome possible suggestions, from workflows, packages, functions, converting the png image to other formats, etc.
Is there already pre-defined code for this? Would I really have to convert the image to svg to access the location of the elements within the png picture? Is it possible to perform these operations in python?
I welcome possible suggestions...

And also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34060142/383904
